# Is synonymy of "man" and "human" on decline?

Tags: synonyms, american-english, language-change

**Is the synonymy of *man* and *human* on the decline? By extension, I am interested in *mankind* and *humankind*.**

I have no idea what online tools to use to investigate this.

Answer (score 2):

If the synonymy of man and human were stagnant over time, one might expect their usage trends to be parallel. The fact that they're not and are, instead, undergoing separation may suggest that the synonymy is in decline. ([Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=man%2Chuman&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chuman%3B%2Cc0))

With mankind and humankind, however, the opposite seems to be true. ([Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mankind%2C%20humankind&year_start=1800&year_end=2016&corpus=15&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmankind%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chumankind%3B%2Cc0))

Google's Ngrams Viewer is the tool I used for this. If you think my logic is sound, you can get there by following the links above.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

When I was studying biology at school in the 1960s, I was once corrected (by a female teacher!) for referring to *humans* instead of *man* in an essay. In the decades since, it has become less and less acceptable to use *man* as a term for the human race. For instance, we say *synthetic fibres* rather than *man-made fibres*.

So the answer to your question is that the synonymy has declined to the point of being virtually non-existent.

Comment: So the answer to your question is that the synonymy has declined to the point of being virtually non-existent. — obviously false, Webster agrees.

Comment: Aleksandr,
While the last sentence in Kate's answer may be a bit of an overstatement, the point she makes is undeniable. As much as I hate voting against myself (especially when my answer has been accepted), this one got a +1 from me. I can think of several arguments for why my Ngrams may be unworthy of the suggestions I've ascribed to them, but, as I've said, there's no arguing with the logic of Kate's post. If there's one thing I've learned on this forum, it's that resources like Websters are often a poor substitute for the experienced mind of a native speaker.